# PostgreSQL как встраиваемая бд для приложения net 3.5

Tags: .net, postgresql

Можно ли использовать PostgreSQL в качестве встроенной субд? т.е. нужно чтобы на машины пользователей не приходилось ставить никаких серверов и дополнительного ПО. И, если это возможно, то каким способом можно выполнять обновление схемы БД на машинах пользователей?

Comment: Говорят нет встраиваемого postgresql-я. И не ожидается.